# Let $f(x,y) = x^6y, x > 0, y >0.$ Show that for each $A>0$ there is $x>0$ such for any $y >0$ arbitrarily small $f(x,y) > A$.

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x,y) = x^6y, x > 0, y >0$ be a smooth function. I would like to show that for each $A>0$ there is $x>0$ such for any $y >0$ arbitrarily small $f(x,y) > A$. This problem comes from an analysis problem that I am working on, and questions related to that have been showing up a lot, but I am not being able to approach problems like these. I appreciate any hint/comment/answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f(x,y) = x^6y, x > 0, y >0.$

Given any $A$, we need to show that for any arbitrary value of $y$, $f(x,y)>A$

Given an $A$, choose $x = \sqrt[\textstyle6]{\dfrac {A}y}+1$. Notice that for this choice of $x $ ,   $f(x,y)>A$

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to use roots, take $x = \sqrt[\textstyle6]{\dfrac {A+1}y}$.

Comment: BTW, the intuition is, "I want $x^6 > \dfrac Ay$"

Comment: thank you, @player3236, I was a little confused, but this is clear now. I just chose the other answer because it was posted first, but I do appreciate your help.